# Error: Install RabbitMQ on Macos sierra

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, macos-sierra

I was trying to install RabbitMQ on my Mac Which is running on Sierra 10.12 , via HomeBrew. 
I wrote `brew install rabbitmq` so that It will automatically install the OpenSSL. 
But it shows the following Error:

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
wxmac: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on OS X
versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with RabbitMQ installed into a Docker container, with Docker for Mac https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/

There's an official RMQ image for docker https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

Be sure to get the ":management" tag

`docker pull rabbitmq:management`

and be sure to map port 5672 and 15672 from the container, when you run it.

I moved my Mac install of RMQ into Docker recently, and won't go back. It's much easier for me to have services like this inside a Docker container.

Comment: how to start rabbitmq in mac with docker?

Answer (score 3):

Update your homebrew.
`brew update` will work. 
If you get `Error: /usr/local is not writable. You should change the ownership`, you should make `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` and after that - `brew update`